# Get-ADUser -Identity

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Unable to pass a variable to the Identity parameter in Powershell.

```
$username = "John.Doe"
Get-ADUser -Identity "$username"
```

```
Get-ADUser : Cannot find an object with identity: 'John.Doe' under: 'DC=contoso,DC=com'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ADUser -Identity "$username"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (John.Doe:ADUser) [Get-ADUser], ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException,M
   icrosoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
```

If I just put Get-ADUser -Identity "John.Doe" the results come back just fine.

Comment: Are you sure that's your `$username` variable? Looks like you have `$username = 'John.Doe@contoso.com'`. Not to mention quotes aren't needed in the `Get-ADUser` function, you could just have `Get-ADUser -Identity $username`

Comment: Looks like I copy / pasted wrong error message. I have updated the post.

Comment: Can you use the `-Server` parameter to guarantee you are querying against the same server in both test cases? Otherwise, I can't replicate this and I've tried on PowerShell versions 2.0, 4.0, and 5.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-Identity` parameter accepts the following:

> - A distinguished name
> - A GUID (objectGUID)
> - A security identifier (objectSid)
> - A SAM account name (sAMAccountName)

If you want to search based on another attribute, then you need to use the `-Filter` switch. For example, to find user based on UserPrincipalName, you can do the following:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName -eq 'John.Doe@contoso.com'"
```

See [Get-ADUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser?view=win10-ps) for more details.

Comment: $username = "John.Doe"
Get-ADUser -Identity "$username"

That is not fully qualifying the UserPrincipleName

Comment: John.Doe@contoso.com is a fully qualified name.

Comment: if `Get-ADUser -Identity "John.Doe"` does not work, then John.Doe is not a SamAccountName. So it should fail.

Comment: I copy and pasted the wrong error message I have updated the OP.

Comment: Where does John.Doe come from? Are you just taking the first name and last name and joining with a dot?

Comment: Get-ADUser -Identity "John.Doe" works if you don't pass the variable.

Comment: Did you try removing the quotes surrounding the variable as Riley Carney suggested? `Get-ADUser -Identity $username`

Comment: Seems to be a replication timing issue. So if the account is created, then the Get-ADUser is pulled on a DC that doesn't have the replicated information it causes the error. Appreciate the information.

Answer (score 2):

I know it is old question but It might be the answer. It might help some one down the line.
I came across the same issue and it stumped me 1 hour. Finally I used $username = $username.trim() . So obviously the variable has space which need to be trimmed.